# Redis SETEX slow

Tags: redis

checking my SLOWLOG in redis 4.0.9, I found this, db no.1:

```
1) 1) (integer) 5194
   2) (integer) 1538107771
   3) (integer) 140185
   4) 1) "SETEX"
      2) "okurl:/en/7055756"
      3) "3600"
      4) "1"
   5) "172.20.100.4:24784"
   6) ""
```

I would like to know, what is possible to cause this. info:

```
# Server
redis_version:4.0.9
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:2fd2284b20453690
redis_mode:standalone
os:FreeBSD 11.2-PRERELEASE amd64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:kqueue
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:4.2.1
process_id:40220
run_id:ec7f3e8144a681f0efca5e980ccdf39b8a8fdb71
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:81007
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:11384428
executable:/usr/local/bin/redis-server
config_file:/usr/local/etc/redis-sessions.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:429
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:5749433062
used_memory_human:5.35G
used_memory_rss:5746385347
used_memory_rss_human:5.35G
used_memory_peak:30520735162
used_memory_peak_human:28.42G
used_memory_peak_perc:18.84%
used_memory_overhead:1280922380
used_memory_startup:1055278
used_memory_dataset:4468510682
used_memory_dataset_perc:77.74%
total_system_memory:0
total_system_memory_human:0B
used_memory_lua:142448640
used_memory_lua_human:135.85M
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.00
mem_allocator:libc
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:28274431
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1538107772
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:35
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:0
aof_enabled:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:232817201
total_commands_processed:1640805022
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:22264
total_net_input_bytes:116006836822
total_net_output_bytes:56698168188
instantaneous_input_kbps:1470.51
instantaneous_output_kbps:639.40
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:28093034
expired_stale_perc:29.33
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:399489929
keyspace_misses:93415724
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:645655
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0


# Keyspace
db0:keys=8517091,expires=8516507,avg_ttl=14897082
db1:keys=4938456,expires=4805686,avg_ttl=1455726323
```

Maybe it is cause just when redis is writing dump file to filesystem, so it slows down ? Or it can be some other blocking command is running ? (I am not using KEYS, but there are other commands which could make this slow down?)

Answer (score 1):

> I am not using KEYS, but there are other commands which could make this slow down?

Commands in the slowlog get there if their respective execution time is long - other commmands do not affect that (e.g. KEYS or anything else).

> checking my SLOWLOG in redis 4.0.9, I found this

Checking the SLOWLOG is a good practice that should be done periodically. That said, a single slow command in it is probably an outlier that's due to any number of reasons. I wouldn't worry about it unless it is pathological.